# Dynamically disable button when a variable reachs a value

Tags: function, react-native, disable

I would like, as I've said on the title, change the state of my button "Annuler" when I reach a certain value of "tab" variable. I obviously verified if my problem weren't similar to another person but I didn' found at all. I also tried to use an arrow function in order to return the value of true or false for some conditions. Also tried with the code below by using "something ? true : false" format. I must necessarily use a function instead of class.  Here's my code :

````
import { StyleSheet , View , ScrollView , Image , Text , FlatList , TouchableHighlight, StatusBar, Button, Alert} from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import modulesData from './Helpers/modulesData.js';

export default function App() {
    ...

    var tab = 0;
    var arr = Array(3);
    var arrstring = arr.toString()
    var i = 0
    var classModules = (module) => {
        arr[tab] = module;
        arr.length = 3;
        tab++;
        if (tab == 3){
        var arrstring = arr.toString()
        Alert.alert("Les modules sélectionnés sont :",arrstring);
        }
    }

    var unfillarray = () => {
        if (tab => 3)
        {
            arr = ['','','']
            tab = 0;
        }
    }

    var disablebutton = false;

    if(fontsLoaded){
        return (
            ...
                <FlatList contentContainerStyle={styles.Flatlist}
                    data={modulesData}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({item}) => 
                        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.DivModule}
                        onLongPress={() => Alert.alert("Description du "+modulesData[item.id - 1].title+" : ",modulesData[item.id - 1].overview)}
                        onPress={() => {classModules(modulesData[item.id -1].title)}}  
                        underlayColor="#D8DFE3">
                            <Text style={{fontSize:16}}>{item.title}</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    }
                />
            <Button title="Annuler" style={{height:50}} color="#FFD48E" onPress={() => {unfillarray()}} disabled={tab == 3 ? false : true }>
        <Text style={{color:"black"}}>
        Annuler
        </Text> 
        </Button>
            </View>
        );
    } else {
        return (
        ...
        );
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    HeaderInfoText:{
    ...
    },

    HeaderInfo:{
    ...
    },

    Flatlist:{
    ...
    },

    DivModule:{
    ...
    }

})```
````

Comment: where is your States and change State? I can't see them ? if your code is incomplete please provide a complete code.

Comment: for this, you need to use State Hook. find out more about state and hooks here.  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: I can't use it cause I'm not on class but only in a function. There is really any solution with my case and should I be constraint to make a class ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to play with the state like this call this function or simply update state:

```
this.state{
 isDisabled: false
}

handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({ isDisabled: !this.state.isDisabled})
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, where do I put this ?

Comment: When I put state object, code considers this.state not valid and ask to add a ";" at the end of "this.state"... I think this is it because I don't have any class